# How to store multiple api's data with VueX and add properties to the response

Tags: vue.js, axios

Suppose i want to store data from multile Api requests - when the App is instantiated, 
and i also want to add properties to each response

Here is the url of the api 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json?lat=LAT&lon=LON'

Updated
I want to instantiated the app with all the data from a couple of get requests - so i'm looping all the requests - that part is works fine , but i also want to be able to add to response.data.response object properties from the cities array, so the finale result will be :

```
   cities: [{
      id: 0,
      cityName: 'Select a city',
      stuff from response.data...
    },......
```

Here is the main part of the Api call

```
       const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
        satelliteData: [],
        dataObj:[],
        loading: true,
        cities: [{
          id: 0,
          cityName: 'Select a city',
          cityLocation: null
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          cityName: 'Tel Aviv',
          cityLat: '32.0853',
          cityLon: '34.7818'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          cityName: 'London',
          cityLat: '51.5074',
          cityLon: '-0.1278'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          cityName: 'New York',
          cityLat: '40.7128',
          cityLon: '-74.0060'
        },
      ],
      },


    actions: {
        loadData({commit}) {
          for(var i=0; i<this.state.cities.length; i++){
            var currData = this.state.cities[i];
            if(!!this.state.cities[i].hasOwnProperty('cityLat'))

            axios.get(URL, {
              params: {
                lat: this.state.cities[i].cityLat,
                lon: this.state.cities[i].cityLon,
              },
            }).then((response) => {

                  Here is where i want to be able to access the Cities array

           /*    var cities = this.$store.state.cities;
                console.log(cities) */
                commit('updateSatelliteData', response.data.response)
                commit('changeLoadingState', false)
              })
          }

        }
      },
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/9ksyc8om/4/)

Since i'm new to Vue - i'm sure that there are a couple of mistakes here. Thanks

Comment: The most common way to call APIs is with a small library called "axios". If you want to call this API and use it in different *child* components, use props and pass the data down. If you want to call the API once and have different components (not children), use a "global store" or "global event bus". If it goes beyond that, "Vuex" is the way to go (which functions as a data store level of the application).

Comment: @BennettDams thanks, i've looked into VueX, but i couldn't figure out how to get what i want with it...any ideas?

Comment: Vuex really makes sense for big projects, a high level of data structures and a lot of data manipulation. For the beginning, I would stick to a global store:  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch

Comment: Since you are trying to interact with data between multiple components (app and posttitle), Vuex is ypour solution (as already said in previous comments)

Comment: @BennettDams Thanks - i've updated the question